# Python - How do I convert number with dash to number

Tags: python

I have a number 3.8148116e-09

How do I convert it to a real number without the - ?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a real number, so what is your question really?

Comment: Is this a string you want to convert to number? or are you asking how to fix the value printed in the console?

Comment: The number with the - is downloaded from an API, but I need it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> a = "3.8148116e-09"
>>> number = float(a)
>>> print "{:1.16f}".format(number)
0.0000000038148116
```

The first line parses the string as a number. If you need to print the number or format it for another reason, you can use string#format.

Comment: Thanks very much 